# Protocol Minecraft Chat Socket Java

Tags: sockets, chat, bots, minecraft, packet

I successfully do an Handshake (ping) via Socket, but now I want to connect the bot to the serveur then listen chat packet.
But I don't understand what is salt, encryption ... in wiki.vg/Protocol
So if someone can help me :)

Comment: This is not even a question

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow, please take a minute to read [How To Ask A Question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and consider updating your question.